# Nodejs - Check for hidden files

Tags: node.js

I'm iterating a directory of files and was wondering if it's possible to test if a file is hidden or not. Currently, I'm just checking if file starts with a '.' or not. This works in Mac (and Linux, maybe), but, I'm wondering how I would do it on Windows? Also, will the period hide the file in all flavors of Linux?

Thanks!

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('/path', function(err, list) {
   list.forEach(function(filename){
       var isHidden = /^\./.test(filename);
        // etc ...
    }); 
});
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to hide files on macOS. The other main way is via a hidden flag in an extra field returned by the `stat()` functions that nodeJS doesn't expose. You can use the terminal command `chflags` to change it and you can see which files use it by doing `ls -lO`

Answer (score 19):

The regular expression to effectively detect hidden files and directory path in Unix would be a bit more complex owing to the possibility of their existence within a long path string.

The following tries to take care of the same.

```
/**
 * Checks whether a path starts with or contains a hidden file or a folder.
 * @param {string} source - The path of the file that needs to be validated.
 * returns {boolean} - `true` if the source is blacklisted and otherwise `false`.
 */
var isUnixHiddenPath = function (path) {
    return (/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g).test(path);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `(/(^|.\/)\.+[^\/\.]/g).test('/.DS_Store');`

Comment: Is a hidden file simply defined as starting with a period?

Comment: Yes - but only on Unix OS. And it can also mean a hidden directory.

Comment: Re: "the possibility of their existence within a long path string..." 
Is that the case for `fs.readdir`?  My understanding is the call only returns names of files in the directory.

Answer (score 8):

Did some quick testing using node 0.6.x on Windows 7. The setup was a folder containing 1 folder, 1 protected, 1 hidden and 1 file without special attributes.

I looped this folder and fetched the stats for the entries (using fs.stat(path, callback)), these are the results:

```
testfolder
fs.Stats.mode: 16895

test_hidden.txt
fs.Stats.mode: 33206

test_norm.txt
fs.Stats.mode: 33206

test_prot.txt
fs.Stats.mode: 33060
```

As you can see, one is able to differ between protected and hidden/normal files through the mode, but the hidden attribute is actually a real attribute and has nothing to do with the file mode.

In order to reliably identify hidden files on Windows, the node.js team would have to implement the GetFileAttributes() API on windows (like it's done by C++ or C#). AFAIK, this is not in the pipeline (at least i found nothing after some quick googling).

For your question concerning files being hidden in all flavors of unix when prefixed by a period: i didn't come across a distribution where this didn't work, so from my pov: yes.

Comment: Testing with files and folders on my Windows desktop. No matter what combination of standard attribute I had applied, all files had a mode of 33060 and all folders had a mode of 16822. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440589/retrieve-file-attributes-from-windows-cmd for a solution using a host script.

Comment: Based on my above link, I wrote a module to handle hidden files simply: https://www.npmjs.org/package/hidefile

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a hard filter and limited mainly to files starting with a dot, I suggest to use the solution mentioned in one of the comments on another post:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/junk

The advantage of going through this module is that it is scalable: if someone adds another file name scheme, you will benefit from it too.

**Code sample:**

```
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import {isNotJunk} from 'junk';

const files = await fs.readdir('some/path');

console.log(files);
//=> ['.DS_Store', 'test.jpg']

console.log(files.filter(isNotJunk));
//=> ['test.jpg']
```