# Determine if file/foder is hidden in Windows via Electron/Node

Tags: node.js, windows, filesystems, electron

Is there a way to determine that a file in Windows is hidden in Electron. I need to know the hidden attribute set in Properties of the file and not file name having a dot at front. Currently using `fs` to get file system information I have no means to obtain this information.

Some sample use case would be (using Typescript):

```
import fs = require('fs');

getVisibleFilesSync(): string[] {
    const folderItems = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    return folderItems.filter(x => !isHidden(x));
}

isHidden(path: string): boolean {
    // how to determine if path is hidden under Windows?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`isHiddenSync`](https://github.com/stevenvachon/hidefile#ishiddensyncpath) function in the [hidefile](https://github.com/stevenvachon/hidefile) module.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I traced back to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440589/retrieve-file-attributes-from-windows-cmd). It's not an exact duplicate (the SO flag-trolls may disagree), so I'll update on what my function `isHidden`'s implementation would be.