# How to ignore hidden files in fs.readdir result

Tags: node.js

In node application i need to get all the files in the directory except that hidden files.
I have tried fs.readdir but it displaying hidden files also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs - Check for hidden files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905680/nodejs-check-for-hidden-files)

Comment: You could (or have to I would say) loop through the files to filter out the "hidden" file.  Check the link above.

Comment: `fs.readdir` should really have a native option to exclude hidden files.

Answer (score 28):

Using the regex from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285137/5373209) answer, this simple solution removes all hidden files from the result:

```
fs.readdir('/path/to/directory', (err, list) => {
  list = list.filter(item => !(/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g).test(item));

  // Your code
});
```

Comment: list = list.filter(item => !(/(^|\/)\.[^/.]/g).test(item)

// Fix in regex.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
fs.readdir('/path/to/directory', function(err, list) {
  list.forEach(function (filename) {
    if(! /^\..*/.test(filename)) {
      // display files
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [junk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junk) package to ignore hidden files.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var junk = require('junk');

fs.readdir('path', function (err, files) {
    console.log(files.filter(junk.not));
});
```

Comment: junk doesn't filter all hidden files. > [`Filter out system junk files like .DS_Store and Thumbs.db`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junk)

Comment: @1252748 Yes. You can define regex to hide what you do not need.

Comment: Then why use the junk module at all? Just filter on `/^\./`. There's no reason to use a module that doesn't do what you want just to filter its results exactly the same way as you could filter the results from `readdir`.

Comment: None of these work, maybe they have some success on UNIX-like systems that use a dot (.) to indicate a hidden directory but in the real world, directories don't have to be prefixed with a dot to be hidden, especially on Windows. Whether a directory is hidden is stored in its attribute, thus Node really should support this natively and not only for hidden folders exclusively but system folders, as well.

Comment: Appears like junk now does filter out .DS_Store and Thumbs.db: https://github.com/sindresorhus/junk/blob/main/index.js

Answer (score 1):

The promise way

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const readdir = path => {
  return fs
    .readdir(path)
    .then(list => list.filter(item => !/(^|\/)\.[^/.]/g.test(item)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression like the solution provided may remove some filesystems but not all files. And using the "Junk" module is using regular expressions on some defined system filenames. So the solution is simply to write a personal script managing the different cases by adding cases as they are discovered.