# Detect hidden/system files and folders in Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to enumerate files and folders with recursion, and then [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) for each file, to get accessibility details.

I need to detect all hidden and system files, based on the information from [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback), so I can skip them from enumeration.

I know we get property `mode` that's supposed to help us, but I cannot find out how to use it properly, so it would work across every OS.

P.S. I saw this question: [How to ingnore hidden files in fs.readdir result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973655/how-to-ingnore-hidden-files-in-fs-readdir-result), but the answers there are no good.